# Call a Sub Within a User Form

Tags: vba, userform

I have a pretty straight-forward question that I cannot seem to get a definite answer on, so asking it here.

I have a user form that works.  Within that form there is a function.  The code for the command button works fine and calls the function just fine.  I can also call subs from other modules just fine.

What I do not seem to be able to do is call a sub that is also within the form.  As I said, the functions work fine as long as prefaced with 'me'.

That does not work for subs though.  I have tried to make the subs private, public, tried Form and Frm as well.  If I run it as 'me' I get an automation error, noting the callee connections have failed.  If I run it as 'Form' I get  an error saying that the object is required.

So my question is...can you call subs that are stored within the same form?  I figured yes given that functions work but it does not seem to be the case.

The reason I want them in the form is so that when I roll it out to users I do not have to also roll out 10 other subs as well.  If I can store them all in the same form, that would be helpful.

Thanks

Here is a portion of the code I am talking about.  Profile1 is the sub I am trying to call, which as you can see is located within the same form.  As noted, it calls the GetBoiler function without an issue.  Included the call to Profile2 just to demonstrate the Form option I tried.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


    findStr = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    Unload Me

    If findStr = "Vendor1" Then Me.Profile1
    If findStr = "Vendor2" Then Form.Profile2
    If findStr = 'Vendor3" Then Me.GetBoiler (SigString)   


   End Sub

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
End Function

Private Sub Profile1()



     Select Case Application.ActiveWindow.Class
           Case olInspector
                Set oMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
           Case olExplorer
                Set oMail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    End Select
              SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Profile1.htm"
```

Comment: `If findStr = "Vendor2" Then Profile2`

Comment: also, `If findStr = "Vendor3" Then call Me.GetBoiler  (SigString)`  or  `If findStr = "Vendor3" Then Me.GetBoiler  SigString`.

Comment: How is it any different than calling any other procedure anywhere else? BTW `Unload Me` in the middle of a procedure, looks very, very wrong.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, I have the unload in there to close the window.  This is actually for Outlook, not Excel.  So everything stops if I do not do that b/c Outlook sees a dialogue box open.  As to your other question, that is what I thought too but for some reason, the function would not call if I did not do it that way.  Maybe it is something with the Outlook properties being a bit different than Excel?  Not really sure, which is why I have gotten so frustrated with it.  I usually do not post until I have beat my head against the wall for a few days first!

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks, that is exactly what I was trying at first but it fails.  If you step through, it actually confirms the If value, goes to Profile2, then just goes to the next line in the code.  It seems to skip over it or not recognize that it is a sub.  This is in Outlook VBA though so maybe that is what is doing it.  It is maddening.  Why would it not do the basic function that VBA relies on in Excel and Access (calling other procedures).

Comment: @cyboashu, thanks, for the function GetBoiler you are absolutely correct, that works and is how I got that to work.  However, that does NOT work for the subs.  Adding the Me causes a run-time error:  Automation error.  The callee(server[not server application]) is not available and disappeared;  all connections are invalid.  The call may have executed.

Comment: I understand. But `Unload Me` means "unload this object instance", and one would rightfully expect that this means any subsequent code doesn't get to run. It's only working because you're working off the form's *default instance*, and that is very much a double-edged blade that's very easy to cut yourself with. That said VBA is VBA, regardless of the host application. Did you read the answer below?

Comment: Also it might be easier to give you a definitive answer if you showed us where and how the `Sub` that's "not working" is declared. Right now it's nowhere and you have 3 procedure calls invoked 3 different ways.

Comment: Okay hold on, I will give you the whole form code but yes, I just finished reading your answer and was just opening your article.  I did try to not qualify it, made the sub public, etc.  It still just skips over it.  Again, it is Outlook and would love to have someone else give it a shot so I know I am not just being stupid!

Comment: Well, you were right again Mahieu!  Read through your article (a bit above my head) and I moved the unload command and boom, it worked.  It now calls the sub.  Now I just need to go through and make sure the rest is working right.  I may be back!  Sorry, I know I said I would post the rest of the code but I have been trying to learn and figure things out on my own, using smarter peoples' advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Me` qualifier refers to the current instance of the class you're in (yes, a form is a class), and gives you the **public members** of that object.

`Profile1` is `Private`, so that member is not on the object's public interface, therefore won't show up in IntelliSense as a member of `Me`.

Just... don't qualify it:

```
If findStr = "Vendor1" Then Profile1
If findStr = "Vendor2" Then Profile2
```

The `GetBoiler` function being implicitly `Public`, the `Me` qualifier works:

```
If findStr = "Vendor3" Then Me.GetBoiler (SigString)
```

Except, you have a *function*, and you're using it as a *procedure*, i.e. you're discarding its return value. When calling a function like this, you need to drop the parentheses:

```
If findStr = "Vendor3" Then GetBoiler SigString
```

Parentheses are otherwise forcing the evaluation of the argument expression, and passing the result `ByVal`, regardless of what the function's signature says - here it says `ByVal` anyway, so the parentheses are purely redundant.

You *do* need the parentheses when you're *not* discarding the function's return value:

```
MsgBox "Message", vbOkOnly
result = MsgBox("Message", vbOkCancel)
```

---

Seeing that `Unload Me` in the middle of a procedure is rather scary. I'd recommend reading [this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) I wrote a little while ago - it's a bit advanced, but very much worth understanding.

Comment: Marked this as answer, as Mathieu's article and explanation of the unload me is what fixed this.  I still have it in (working to see on removing it altogether) but moved it below the code for calling the subs and that worked!